# Google Cloud Vision API - OCR does not return symbols entries

Tags: google-cloud-vision

We are working with a scientific PDF documents created in Asian languages like Japanese  and Chinese. We are using `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` feature type for Cloud Vision API to get text from this documents as it is suggested in documentation. We have requirements to highlight blocks, words and characters (symbols) in our web application and let user to further process the highlighted areas on pdf preview. We can not always display highlights for symbols because of lack of `boundingBox` property in the response for [symbols](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#symbol).
Based on API documentation this property should be present in the response. There is no mention about such option.

The questions are:

- When `boundingBox` for symbols is available?
- What we can do to enforce this property in the response?
- Which factors decide about availability of this property in the response?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is related with known issue for not receiving `bounding boxes` for symbols.

This issue was already reported to google by `Issue Tracker` and it can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190182628).

You can track status of this issue and provide your example there which can help analyze and fix this issue faster.